# react route is changing but html not rendering until i refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
  import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
  import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
  import indexRoutes from "./routes/index";
  import "./index.css";

  var hist = createBrowserHistory();
```

index.js

```
  ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={hist}>
        <Suspense fallback={
        <div></div>}> 
            <Switch>
              {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
                return <Route exact={prop.exact} path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />;
              })}
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

routes.js  - below data is getting passed to index.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  const Home = React.lazy(() => import('../views/Home.view'));
  const Auth = React.lazy(() => import('../views/Auth.view'));
  const Test = React.lazy(() => import('../views/test'));

  var indexRoutes = [
    { exact:false, path: "/test", name: "Test", component: Test },
    { exact:false, path: "/dashboard/", name: "Home", component: Home },
    { exact:true, path: "/", name: "Auth", component: Auth },
  ];

  export default indexRoutes;
```

database.js

inside **"/dashboard/"** route i have below component. Here i have another inner route for some components.
Here when i am going to different route though  the route is changing but the html 
is not rendering. But when i refresh the page the **Databases** component is rendering , **NewReport** component is coming 
when i am going to /**dashboard** route but **Databases** component not working on **/dashboard/databases/** route

**Note:** on refresh the page the Databases component is working

```
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={NewReport} />
    <Route exact path='/dashboard/databases/' component={Databases} />
  </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use only single Router in the whole app, but you are using two different Routers:

- Router - inside index.js
- BrowserRouter - inside /dashboard

You have to remove BrowserRouter and it may fix unexpected behavior